# The navigation bar is being ripped apart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Problem with one of my script.

The main problem is that the `<ul>` once it appears it rips the navigation system apart.

The red part is the “sub”- `<ul>` with the links are it should actually appear to the right of the `ul li` and leave the navigation like in the left picture.

Could someone please help me?

[image: my navigation bar]

http://jsfiddle.net/rTDzk/

and the jQuery:

```
function nav() {
    $('ul li').mouseover(function () {
        $(this).find('.submenu').show();
    });
    $('ul li').mouseleave(function () {
        $('ul li .submenu').hide();
    });
    $('ul li .submenu').mouseleave(function () {
        $('ul li .submenu').hide();;
    });
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    nav();
});
```

The HTML-Code:

```
<ul class="noBullet">
    <li><a href="#home">home</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#lager">lager</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="http://www.mashable.com">Mashable</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.cnet.com">CNET</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#anlaesseN">anlaesseN</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#images">images</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

**update**:

ok this the jsfiddle below worked but now it looks like this[image: this]

Answer (score 0):

This is only a css problem.

Here take a look:

```
.noBullet > li { position: relative; }
.submenu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    z-index: 1000;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: none;
    left:100px;
    top: 0;
}
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rTDzk/1/)

I don't why you prefered it to be relative, but when you position it absolutely it becomes easier and more manageable.

**Second version:**

```
.noBullet { position: relative; }
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rTDzk/2/)

Comment: thanks for your help 
I have an other Problem whit my css...
You changed the Position from relative to absolute - that works well the new problem is that when I use a other link like Fotos it displays it at the same place... 
Is ther a way to  change the Css so I can use this for all my list?

Comment: The first version is displaying it from the top of the list, the second version one is displaying it at the same place. Or I'm missing something.

Comment: Yep you are using the second version of my code. (where the position relative is on the ".noBullet " element). I putted 2 versions because I was not sure if you want your drop down to be placed always at the same place or not. Add position relative, to the children elements of the .noBullet ( .noBullet > li { position: relative; } )